PySpark Accessing outer query column is not allowed in LocalLimit 1 error
I have below PySpark sql query -
facets_query = f"""select
                clcl.CLCL_ID
                ,clcl.CLCL_LOW_SVC_DT ,clcl.CLCL_HIGH_SVC_DT
                ,meme.MEME_FIRST_NAME ,meme.MEME_LAST_NAME ,meme.MEME_HEALTH_ID
                ,prpr.PRPR_NAME
                ,clcl.CSPI_ID ,clcl.PDPD_ID ,clmLine.CDML_SEQ_NO ,clmLine.IPCD_ID ,grgr.GRGR_ID ,sgsg.SGSG_ID
                ,case memd_mepi.MEMD_ACCESS_FMT_NVL when '' then 'Standard' when 'L' then 'Large Print' else 'Standard' end as preference
                ,meme.MEME_MCTR_LANG
                ,sbad_mail.SBAD_ADDR1 ,sbad_mail.SBAD_ADDR2 ,sbad_mail.SBAD_CITY ,sbad_mail.SBAD_STATE ,sbad_mail.SBAD_ZIP ,sbad_mail.SBAD_TYPE ,'US' COUNTRY_CODE
                ,memd_pbp.MEMD_MCTR_PBP ,memd_pbp.MEMD_SEGMENT_ID ,memd_pbp.MEMD_HCFA_EFF_DT ,memd_pbp.MEMD_HCFA_TERM_DT
                ,atad.ATAD_NAME ,atad.ATAD_ADDR1 ,atad.ATAD_ADDR2 ,atad.ATAD_CITY ,atad.ATAD_STATE ,atad.ATAD_ZIP
            from
                facetsdb_dbo_cmc_clcl_claim clcl
                join facetsdb_dbo_cmc_meme_member meme on meme.MEME_CK = clcl.MEME_CK
                join facetsdb_dbo_cmc_prpr_prov prpr on prpr.PRPR_ID = clcl.PRPR_ID
                LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
                        select cdml.CDML_SEQ_NO ,cdml.IPCD_ID
                        from facetsdb_dbo_cmc_cdml_cl_line cdml
                        where clcl.CLCL_ID = cdml.CLCL_ID and cdml.CDML_SEQ_NO = null
                        group by cdml.CDML_SEQ_NO ,cdml.IPCD_ID
                    ) clmLine
                join facetsdb_dbo_cmc_grgr_group grgr on grgr.GRGR_CK = clcl.GRGR_CK
                join facetsdb_dbo_cmc_sgsg_sub_group sgsg on sgsg.SGSG_CK = clcl.SGSG_CK
                LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
                        select U.ATXR_SOURCE_ID ,U.ATSY_ID ,U.ATXR_DEST_ID ,D.ATAD_NAME ,D.ATAD_ADDR1 ,D.ATAD_ADDR2 ,D.ATAD_CITY ,D.ATAD_STATE ,D.ATAD_ZIP
                        from facetsdb_dbo_cer_atxr_attach_u U
                            join facetsdb_dbo_cer_atad_address_d D on U.ATXR_DEST_ID = D.ATXR_DEST_ID and U.ATSY_ID = D.ATSY_ID
                        where U.ATXR_SOURCE_ID = clcl.ATXR_SOURCE_ID
                        order by U.ATXR_DEST_ID desc limit 1
                    ) atad
                left join facetsdb_dbo_cmc_memd_mecr_detl memd_mepi on meme.MEME_CK = memd_mepi.MEME_CK and 'MEPI' = memd_mepi.MEMD_EVENT_CD and '9999-12-31' = memd_mepi.MEMD_HCFA_TERM_DT
                left join facetsdb_dbo_cmc_sbad_addr sbad_mail on meme.SBSB_CK = sbad_mail.SBSB_CK and meme.SBAD_TYPE_MAIL = sbad_mail.SBAD_TYPE
                left join facetsdb_dbo_cmc_memd_mecr_detl memd_pbp on meme.MEME_CK = memd_pbp.MEME_CK and 'PBP' = memd_pbp.MEMD_EVENT_CD and '9999-12-31' = memd_pbp.MEMD_HCFA_TERM_DT
            where
                clcl.CLCL_ID in {claim_id_values}
            """

            logging.info(facets_query)

            facets_details_df = self.spark.sql(facets_query)

But it is giving below error -
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Accessing outer query column is not allowed in:
LocalLimit 1

After bit digging into the issue the root cause seems to be the where clause in 2nd LEFT JOIN LATERAL -
where U.ATXR_SOURCE_ID = clcl.ATXR_SOURCE_ID

When I remove above line the query executes successfully.
Can anyone help me to understand why the error is only for 2nd lateral join as the 1st lateral join also has the column referring from outer query ?
Any help would be appreciated as I am stuck completely.
Thanks in advance !!

I'm guessing it's because you have a limit 1 (see the error message). This doesn't seem to have anything to do with sql server though

@siggemannen as I said if I remove the where clause from 2nd lateral join it works even with limit 1.

well, when you remove the where, you remove the outer column reference that it's complaining about

Thanks @siggemannen for providing your thoughts, then what you suggest here ? As I need that limit clause

i'm no spark expert, but if you remove the order by / limit and add a row_number() over(order by U.ATXR_DEST_ID desc) as sortOrder column inside the lateral join, you can use it in your where clause to only get one row, like: where clcl.CLCL_ID in {claim_id_values} and ISNULL(atad.sortOrder, 1) = 1 . But not sure it supports this function
